# How to return my query to multidimensional array using joins?

Tags: php, sql, join, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to result any sql query into multidimensional array? In my case if I have a player with multiple teams.. how do I need to get a result like this

```
array(
      'fname' => 'Mark',
      'lname' => 'Caguioa',
      'teams' => array(
           'team' => 'Ginebra',
           'team' => 'Hotshots'
      )
)
```

And my idea in my query but it's not working...

```
$stmt = $this->sql->prepare("
        SELECT
        usr.fname,
        usr.lname,
        (
            SELECT
            team.name
            FROM users usr
            LEFT JOIN teams team
            ON usr.gen_id = team.gen_id
        ) AS to 'teams'
        FROM users usr          
    ");
$stmt->execute(array(':gen_id' => 'generated_id'));
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Any idea how to come up with this problem? Any help is very appreciated

Comment: i don't think that you can achieve this approach directly , you will have to iterate over results and reformat you final array

Comment: @HassanAhmed yeah, that's what I'm thinking.. I'm checking if it's possible in any advanced sql query.. If not, like what you said I need to iterate the results of the query. Anyway, thanks!